# How do I find out which js file is responsible for a certain element?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am testing my page in Chrome. I right click on the element that I am having issues with and I get this:

```
element.style {
height: 147px;
position: relative;
width: 100%;
overflow: hidden;
}
```

without a file attached to it. This tells me that the element style is coming from either an inline code (my page has none) or a js file (which my page has a number).

When I turn off the position: relative, I no longer have any issues.

I think I have narrowed it down to one js file that is screwing up my page, but I don't have a clue as to how to fix it or how to figure it out.

Here are some images better describing the issue:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtD71.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8OOV.png

If you look at the first image, the blue box over the image needs to be directly over the orange box so that everything lines up properly.

In the second image, when I turn off the position, the image is positions correctly under the overlay.

My problem is that I don't know enough about js to fix the code to fix the position.

Here is the code that I think is responsible, if it helps.

```
    /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */
/* Entry Slider
 /* ---------------------------------------------------------------------- */

if ($().cycle) {

    var entrySliders = $('.entry-slider > ul');

    $.fn.cycle.transitions.scrollHorizontal = function ($cont, $slides, opts) {
        $cont.css('overflow', 'hidden');
        opts.before.push($.fn.cycle.commonReset);
        var w = $cont.width();
        opts.cssFirst.left = 0;
        opts.cssBefore.left = w;
        opts.cssBefore.top = 0;
        opts.animIn.left = 0;
        opts.animOut.left = 0 - w;

        if ($cont.data('dir') === 'prev') {
            opts.cssBefore.left = -w;
            opts.animOut.left = w;
        }
    };

    function initEntrySlider(entrySliders, isFirstTime) {
        entrySliders.each(function (i) {
            var slider = $(this);
            var initPerformed = isFirstTime && slider.data('initInvoked');
            if (!initPerformed) {
                slider.data('initInvoked', 'true');

                var sliderId = 'entry-slider-' + i;
                slider.attr('id', sliderId);
                var prevButtonId = sliderId + '-prev';
                var nextButtonId = sliderId + '-next';

                if (slider.data('enable') === 'false') {
                    return;
                }

                slider.css('height', slider.children('li:first').height());
                var firstSlide = slider.children('li')[0];
                var lastSlide = slider.children('li')[slider.children('li').length - 1];

                if (slider.children('li').length > 1) {
                    if (slider.parent().find('#' + prevButtonId).length == 0) {
                        slider.parent().append('<div class="entry-slider-nav"><a id="' + prevButtonId + '" class="prev">Prev</a><a id="' + nextButtonId + '" class="next">Next</a></div>');
                    }
                }

                slider.cycle({
                    onPrevNextEvent: function (isNext, zeroBasedSlideIndex, slideElement) {
                        $(slideElement).parent().data('dir', isNext ? 'next' : 'prev');
                    },
                    before: function (curr, next, opts, forwardFlag) {
                        var $this = $(this);
                        var sliderId = $this.closest('ul').attr('id');
                        // set the container's height to that of the current slide
                        $this.parent().stop().animate({height: $this.height()}, opts.speed);
                        if (opts['nowrap']) {
                            var prevButton = $('#' + sliderId + '-prev');
                            var nextButton = $('#' + sliderId + '-next');
                            if ((firstSlide == next) && (!prevButton.hasClass('disabled'))) {
                                prevButton.addClass('disabled');
                            } else {
                                prevButton.removeClass('disabled');
                            }

                            if ((lastSlide == next) && (!nextButton.hasClass('disabled'))) {
                                nextButton.addClass('disabled');
                            } else {
                                nextButton.removeClass('disabled');
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    containerResize: false,
                    pauseOnPagerHover: true,
                    nowrap: false, // if true, the carousel will not be circular
                    easing: 'easeInOutExpo',
                    fx: 'scrollHorizontal',
                    speed: 600,
                    timeout: 0,
                    fit: true,
                    width: '100%',
                    pause: true,
                    slideResize: true,
                    slideExpr: 'li',
                    prev: '#' + prevButtonId,
                    next: '#' + nextButtonId
                });
            }
        });
        if (Modernizr.touch && $().swipe) {
            function doEntrySliderSwipe(e, dir) {
                var sliderId = $(e.currentTarget).attr('id');
                if (dir == 'left') {
                    $('#' + sliderId + '-next').trigger('click');
                }
                if (dir == 'right') {
                    $('#' + sliderId + '-prev').trigger('click');
                }
            }

            entrySliders.each(function () {
                var slider = $(this);
                var initPerformed = isFirstTime && slider.data('swipeInvoked');
                if (!initPerformed) {
                    slider.data('swipeInvoked', 'true');
                    slider.swipe({
                        click: function (e, target) {
                            $(target).trigger('click');
                        },
                        swipeLeft: doEntrySliderSwipe,
                        swipeRight: doEntrySliderSwipe,
                        allowPageScroll: 'auto'
                    });
                }
            });

        }

    }

    function initAllEntrySliders(isFirstTime) {
        if (isFirstTime) {
            var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                window.clearTimeout(timer);
                initEntrySlider($('.entry-slider > ul'), isFirstTime);
            }, 100);
        } else {
            initEntrySlider($('.entry-slider > ul'), isFirstTime);
        }
    }

    function resizeEntrySlider(entrySliders) {
        entrySliders.each(function () {
            var slider = $(this);
            slider.css('height', slider.children('li:first').height());
        });
    }

    function loadEntrySlider() {
        var entrySliderImages = $('.entry-slider > ul > li> a > img');
        var unloadedImagesCount = 0;
        var unloadedImages = [];
        entrySliderImages.each(function () {
            if (!this.complete && this.complete != undefined) {
                unloadedImages.push(this);
                unloadedImagesCount++;
            }
        });
        if (unloadedImagesCount == 0) {
            initAllEntrySliders(true);
        } else {
            var initAllEntrySlidersInvoked = false;
            var loadedImagesCount = 0;
            $(unloadedImages).bind('load', function () {
                loadedImagesCount++;
                if (loadedImagesCount === unloadedImagesCount) {
                    if (!initAllEntrySlidersInvoked) {
                        initAllEntrySlidersInvoked = true;
                        initAllEntrySliders(true);
                    }
                }
            });
            var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
                window.clearTimeout(timer);
                $(unloadedImages).each(function () {
                    if (this.complete || this.complete === undefined) {
                        $(this).trigger('load');
                    }
                });
            }, 50);

        }
    }

    loadEntrySlider();

    $(window).on('resize', function () {
        var timer = window.setTimeout(function () {
            window.clearTimeout(timer);
            resizeEntrySlider(entrySliders);
        }, 30);
    });

}
```

And if I should be asking this somewhere else or something, let me know.

Comment: The only way to find out is by inspection.

Comment: Can you grep your code for the styles?

Comment: I don't use InDesign, just notepad++